# Change text of class using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, class

I'm new to Javascript,

I want to change a certain text using Javascript, for exemple I have:

```
<div class="main">
   <div class="price_box"> 0€ </div>
   <div class="price_box"> 100€ </div>
   <div class="price_box"> 45€ </div>
</div>
```

I want to change **only** the "0€" to "price on request", but all I can do is change them all.

I used this (idk if its right or not)

```
function PriceOnRequest()
    {
        
    x=document.getElementsByClassName("price_box");

        /*for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
        x[i].innerText="Price On Request";    // Changes all of them
        }*/
        
        /*for(x.innerText == '0€'){
            x.innerText="Price On Request"; 
        }*/
        
        if(x.innerText == '0€'){
            x.innerText="Price On Request"; 
        }

    }
```

Comment: take a read about pseudo-classes to select only 1st `.price_box`

Comment: Do you want to change the first or the one containing 0€?

Comment: "but all I can do is change them all" - could you show us the code you tried that with ([mcve])?

Comment: I want to change the one with "0€" not the position of it.

Comment: Since `getElementyByClassName()` returns a `HTMLCollection`, you can't do `innerText` directly like you can't do that on an array. Instead, you have to loop over it in order to use your if condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll(".price_box")].forEach(div => {
  if (div.textContent.trim() === '0€') div.textContent = "Price on request";
})
```

```html
<div class="main">
   <div class="price_box"> 100€ </div>
   <div class="price_box"> 0€ </div>
   <div class="price_box"> 45€ </div>
</div>
```

Note I use the spread operator to make it complatible with early EDGE

If your do not care, change to

```
document.querySelectorAll(".price_box").forEach(div => {
```

Comment: Instead of `innerText`, it's recommended to use `textContent` to prevent unnecessary re-renders.

Comment: @shaedrich You are correct. I normally use textContent but had innerHTML in my head

Comment: @JoãoSilva Note I changed to textContent instead of innerText - they both work, but textContent is the preferrred/recommended entity

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the pricing elements and replace the text.

```js
const applyPricing = (selector, zeroText, replacement) => 
  document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(priceBox => {
    if (priceBox.textContent.trim() === zeroText) {
      priceBox.textContent = replacement;
    }
  });

applyPricing('.price_box', '0€', 'Price upon request');
```

```css
.main { border: thin solid grey; }
.price_box { border: thin solid grey; margin: 0.5em; padding: 0.5em; }
```

```html
<div class="main">
   <div class="price_box"> 0€ </div>
   <div class="price_box"> 100€ </div>
   <div class="price_box"> 45€ </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could use a `Map` for multiple replacements.

```js
const applyPricing = (selector, replMap) => 
  document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(priceBox => {
    const key = priceBox.textContent.trim();
    if (replMap.has(key)) {
      priceBox.textContent = replMap.get(key);
    }
  });

const replMap = new Map(Object.entries({
  '0€': 'Price upon request',
  // More replacements ...
}));

applyPricing('.price_box', replMap);
```

```css
.main { border: thin solid grey; }
.price_box { border: thin solid grey; margin: 0.5em; padding: 0.5em; }
```

```html
<div class="main">
   <div class="price_box"> 0€ </div>
   <div class="price_box"> 100€ </div>
   <div class="price_box"> 45€ </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it is a bit complex for the type of problem it is, I am no professional to judge, but I am sure I will use this code in the future. thank you again

Answer (score 0):

If it's always the first one (starting at index 0), you can do the following:

```js
var firstPriceBox = document.getElementsByClassName('price_box')[0];
firstPriceBox.textContent = 'Price On Request';
```

```html
<div class="main">
   <div class="price_box"> 0€ </div>
   <div class="price_box"> 100€ </div>
   <div class="price_box"> 45€ </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can solve this using [`document.evaluate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate) ([XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript)):

```js
var match = document.evaluate(
  "//div[@class='price_box' and contains(., '0€')]",
  document.querySelector('.main'),
  null,
  XPathResult.ANY_TYPE,
  null
);
var priceBox = match.iterateNext();

priceBox.textContent = "Modified contents";
```

```html
<div class="main">
   <div class="price_box"> 0€ </div>
   <div class="price_box"> 100€ </div>
   <div class="price_box"> 45€ </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And it would be more elegant to do `document.querySelector('.price_box')`

Comment: Isn't it? Do you know something, I don't? Nowhere in the question I read, that it can explicitly **any** element.

Comment: It would. But since the TO is new to JavaScript, they should be able to understand it.

Comment: Yes I do, I asked and OP answered in a comment

Comment: What does "not the position of it" mean? Nobody talked about re-ordering the elements.

Comment: I speak `non-native-english` ;)

Comment: Nowhere does it say "I want to change the FIRST element with `0€`"

Comment: Me too. But the quote was taken from the TO not from your comment. But I assume, they are also not a mother tongue. Nowhere do I say say "It definetely always IS the first one" I just provided an example in case it's always the first one.

Comment: Sorry for that, my mistake, I forgot to write, "I want to change the '0€' no matter the position if it", but thank you, this will help me in future problems

Comment: No problem :) @mplungjan's answer should do the job

Comment: Anyway, I added an alternative solution to my question.

Answer (score -2):

You could add an **id** to the div tag.
Then you can **query** the **id** and **assign** its **inner text** to your chosen **string**.

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="price_box" id="price_box1"> 0€ </div>
  <div class="price_box"> 100€ </div>
  <div class="price_box"> 45€ </div>
</div>

<script>
  document.getElementById("price_box1").innerText = "price on request";
</script>
```